# How the Angular HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule url is defined?

Tags: angular

In https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 the in-memory web api is used from another service by using url

```
private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api
```

changing this breaks the app. How does it work if the url is defined only in calling code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of link above the name of the array containing the items defines the url. So changing the url

```
private heroesUrl = 'api/heroesmod';  // URL to web api
```

works if the name of the array is changed as well.

```
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroesmod = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {heroesmod};
  }
```

Only the name after the backslash is important. it works even with url

```
private heroesUrl = 'apimod/heroesmod';  // URL to web api
```